# DefaultMediaHelper.getScreenWidth() function is throwing error when useragent is null

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

we are getting 500 Internal Server Error for all pages in website if we set Useragent to null. while rendering the page, DefaultMediaHelper.getScreenWidth() is throwing this error in DXA logs

```
14:19:57.481 [ajp-nio-9024-exec-500] ERROR c.s.w.c.i.c.ContextEngineImpl - Exception getting claims from provider com.sdl.webapp.tridion.contextengine.ContextServiceClaimsProvider@7c16fcd6
com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: An error occurred while resolving evidence using the Context Service.
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.contextengine.ContextServiceClaimsProvider.getContextClaims(ContextServiceClaimsProvider.java:105)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.contextengine.ContextEngineImpl.claims(ContextEngineImpl.java:52)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.contextengine.ContextEngineImpl.getClaims(ContextEngineImpl.java:32)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.contextengine.ContextEngineImpl.getClaims(ContextEngineImpl.java:42)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.displayWidth(WebRequestContextImpl.java:234)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.getDisplayWidth(WebRequestContextImpl.java:70)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2bfec188.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3bac1b78.getDisplayWidth(<generated>)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.DefaultMediaHelper.getScreenWidth(DefaultMediaHelper.java:155)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:139)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.controller.GenericPageController.handleGetPage(GenericPageController.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:476)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sdl.context.api.exception.ResolverException: Unable serialize evidence argument
    at com.sdl.context.odata.client.ODataContextEngineProxy.resolve(ODataContextEngineProxy.java:92)
    at com.sdl.context.odata.client.api.ODataContextEngine.resolve(ODataContextEngine.java:46)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.contextengine.ContextServiceClaimsProvider.getContextClaims(ContextServiceClaimsProvider.java:101)
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientException: Caught exception NullPointerException:null when serialising evidence into json format
    at com.sdl.context.odata.client.ODataContextEngineProxy.getSerializedEvidence(ODataContextEngineProxy.java:215)
    at com.sdl.context.odata.client.ODataContextEngineProxy.resolve(ODataContextEngineProxy.java:90)
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sdl.context.odata.serialization.EvidenceSerializer.serialize(EvidenceSerializer.java:23)
    at com.sdl.context.odata.client.ODataContextEngineProxy.getSerializedEvidence(ODataContextEngineProxy.java:213)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

we using DXA 2.0 with tridion 8.5 for our client website.

Comment: Any particular reason for setting it to null in the first place?

Comment: @AtilaSos I believe the requests coming to the website doesn't have the user-agent (bots most likely)